# Canvas Jquery adding link a href

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

.....

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

ctx.clearRect(pt.x-w/2, pt.y-7, w,14)

ctx.font = "bold 11px Arial"

ctx.textAlign = "center"

ctx.fillStyle = "#888888"

ctx.fillText(label||"", pt.x, pt.y+4)
```

.....

How can I add more attributes to this text like on click open a url, on hover do something, etc

Comment: @thecodeparadox Thanks for the formatting edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parts that make up a canvas are not HTML elements. You cannot attach events to them, and indeed there is no individual memory of any one component; as soon as you commit it to the canvass, it is merged as one picture with everything else.

The workaround is to remember the coordinates yourself of where things are and then, when a click is registered on the canvass, to interpret what it means manually.

This is non-trivial, and there are many libraries that automate this sort of thing. [Have a look at **KineticJS**](http://www.kineticjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Utkanos said, you could also overlay an html link (`<a href=""></a>`) element using css is positioning and styling.